# PySpark and time series data: how to smartly avoid overlapping dates?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the following sample Spark dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

raw_df = pd.DataFrame([
    (1115, dt.datetime(2019,8,5,18,20), dt.datetime(2019,8,5,18,40)),
    (484, dt.datetime(2019,8,5,18,30), dt.datetime(2019,8,9,18,40)),
    (484, dt.datetime(2019,8,4,18,30), dt.datetime(2019,8,6,18,40)),
    (484, dt.datetime(2019,8,2,18,30), dt.datetime(2019,8,3,18,40)),
    (484, dt.datetime(2019,8,7,18,50), dt.datetime(2019,8,9,18,50)),
    (1115, dt.datetime(2019,8,6,18,20), dt.datetime(2019,8,6,18,40)),
], columns=['server_id', 'start_time', 'end_time'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(raw_df)
```

which result in

```
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
|server_id|         start_time|           end_time|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
|     1115|2019-08-05 18:20:00|2019-08-05 18:40:00|
|      484|2019-08-05 18:30:00|2019-08-09 18:40:00|
|      484|2019-08-04 18:30:00|2019-08-06 18:40:00|
|      484|2019-08-02 18:30:00|2019-08-03 18:40:00|
|      484|2019-08-07 18:50:00|2019-08-09 18:50:00|
|     1115|2019-08-06 18:20:00|2019-08-06 18:40:00|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

This indicates the usage date ranges of each server. I want to convert this into a time series of non-overlapping dates.

I would like to achieve this **without using UDFs**.

This is what I'm doing now, which is wrong

```
w = Window().orderBy(fn.lit('A'))
# Separate start/end date of usage into rows
df = (df.withColumn('start_end_time', fn.array('start_time', 'end_time'))
    .withColumn('event_dt', fn.explode('start_end_time'))
    .withColumn('row_num', fn.row_number().over(w)))
# Indicate start/end date of the usage (start date will always be on odd rows)
df = (df.withColumn('is_start', fn.when(fn.col('row_num')%2 == 0, 0).otherwise(1))
    .select('server_id', 'event_dt', 'is_start'))
```

which gives

```
+---------+-------------------+--------+
|server_id|           event_dt|is_start|
+---------+-------------------+--------+
|     1115|2019-08-05 18:20:00|       1|
|     1115|2019-08-05 18:40:00|       0|
|      484|2019-08-05 18:30:00|       1|
|      484|2019-08-09 18:40:00|       0|
|      484|2019-08-04 18:30:00|       1|
|      484|2019-08-06 18:40:00|       0|
|      484|2019-08-02 18:30:00|       1|
|      484|2019-08-03 18:40:00|       0|
|      484|2019-08-07 18:50:00|       1|
|      484|2019-08-09 18:50:00|       0|
|     1115|2019-08-06 18:20:00|       1|
|     1115|2019-08-06 18:40:00|       0|
+---------+-------------------+--------+
```

But **the end result I would like to achieve is the following**:

```
+---------+-------------------+--------+
|server_id|           event_dt|is_start|
+---------+-------------------+--------+
|     1115|2019-08-05 18:20:00|       1|
|     1115|2019-08-05 18:40:00|       0|
|     1115|2019-08-06 18:20:00|       1|
|     1115|2019-08-06 18:40:00|       0|
|      484|2019-08-02 18:30:00|       1|
|      484|2019-08-03 18:40:00|       0|
|      484|2019-08-04 18:30:00|       1|
|      484|2019-08-09 18:50:00|       0|
+---------+-------------------+--------+
```

So for `server_id` 484 I have the actual start and end dates without all the noise in between.

Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve that without using UDFs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, this is one of the problems which can be resolved by using Window **lag()**, **sum()** function to add a sub-group label for ordered consecutive rows which match some specific conditions. Similar to what we do in Pandas using **shift()**+**cumsum()**.

1. Set up the Window Spec `w1`:

   ```
   w1 = Window.partitionBy('server_id').orderBy('start_time')
   ```

   and calculate the following:

   - **max**('end_time'): the max `end_time` before the current row over window-`w1`
   - **lag**('end_time'): the previous `end_time`
   - **sum**('prev_end_time < current_start_time ? 1 : 0'): the flag to identify the sub-group

   The above three items can be corresponding to Pandas *cummax()*, *shift()* and *cumsum()*.
2. Calculate *df1* by updating *df.end_time* with `max(end_time).over(w1)` and setting up the sub-group label **g**, then doing `groupby(server_id, g)` to calculate the `min(start_time)` and `max(end_time)`

   ```
   df1 = df.withColumn('end_time', fn.max('end_time').over(w1)) \
           .withColumn('g', fn.sum(fn.when(fn.lag('end_time').over(w1) < fn.col('start_time'),1).otherwise(0)).over(w1)) \
           .groupby('server_id', 'g') \
           .agg(fn.min('start_time').alias('start_time'), fn.max('end_time').alias('end_time'))

   df1.show()
   +---------+---+-------------------+-------------------+
   |server_id|  g|         start_time|           end_time|
   +---------+---+-------------------+-------------------+
   |     1115|  0|2019-08-05 18:20:00|2019-08-05 18:40:00|
   |     1115|  1|2019-08-06 18:20:00|2019-08-06 18:40:00|
   |      484|  0|2019-08-02 18:30:00|2019-08-03 18:40:00|
   |      484|  1|2019-08-04 18:30:00|2019-08-09 18:50:00|
   +---------+---+-------------------+-------------------+
   ```
3. After we have *df1*, we can split the data using two selects and then union the resultset:

   ```
   df_new = df1.selectExpr('server_id', 'start_time as event_dt', '1 as is_start').union(
            df1.selectExpr('server_id', 'end_time as event_dt', '0 as is_start')
   )        

   df_new.orderBy('server_id', 'event_dt').show()                                                                            
   +---------+-------------------+--------+
   |server_id|           event_dt|is_start|
   +---------+-------------------+--------+
   |      484|2019-08-02 18:30:00|       1|
   |      484|2019-08-03 18:40:00|       0|
   |      484|2019-08-04 18:30:00|       1|
   |      484|2019-08-09 18:50:00|       0|
   |     1115|2019-08-05 18:20:00|       1|
   |     1115|2019-08-05 18:40:00|       0|
   |     1115|2019-08-06 18:20:00|       1|
   |     1115|2019-08-06 18:40:00|       0|
   +---------+-------------------+--------+
   ```