# PySpark: How to create a time since last event counter and unique identifiers based on event?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this. To do the required manipulations in standard pandas, I would do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
case = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                  'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
                  'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 1, 0])
year = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
        2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
        2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]

dict = {'case': case, 'y': y, 'year': year}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# the transformations of interest
df['case_id'] = ((~(df.case == df.case.shift())) | (df.y.shift()==1)).cumsum()
df['counter'] = df.groupby(((df['case_id'] != df['case_id'].shift(1))).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

I am looking for help as to how to translate these two commands into a PySpark dataframe.

```
df['case_id'] = ((~(df.case == df.case.shift())) | (df.y.shift()==1)).cumsum()
df['counter'] = df.groupby(((df['case_id'] != df['case_id'].shift(1))).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Expected output looks like:

```
  case  y   year    case_id counter
    A   0   2016    1        0
    A   1   2017    1        1
    A   0   2018    2        0
    A   0   2019    2        1
    B   0   2016    3        0
    B   1   2017    3        1
    B   0   2018    4        0
    B   0   2019    4        1
    C   0   2016    5        0
    C   0   2017    5        1
    C   1   2018    5        2
    C   0   2019    6        0
```

Comment: It seems like you need to use the `LAG()` window function. Can you write a sample of the expected output?

Comment: sample output added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost like an FAQ, see also another example from my old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57739288/9510729). For this example, you can try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

pdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

w1 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('case', 'year')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('case_id').orderBy('case', 'year')

df_new = pdf.withColumn("case_id", F.sum(F.when(~(F.col("case") == F.lag("case").over(w1)) | (F.lag("y",1,0).over(w1) == 1),1).otherwise(0)).over(w1)+1) \
    .withColumn('counter', F.count('*').over(w2)-1)

df_new.show()
+----+---+----+-------+-------+
|case|  y|year|case_id|counter|
+----+---+----+-------+-------+
|   A|  0|2016|      1|      0|
|   A|  1|2017|      1|      1|
|   A|  0|2018|      2|      0|
|   A|  0|2019|      2|      1|
|   B|  0|2016|      3|      0|
|   B|  1|2017|      3|      1|
|   B|  0|2018|      4|      0|
|   B|  0|2019|      4|      1|
|   C|  0|2016|      5|      0|
|   C|  0|2017|      5|      1|
|   C|  1|2018|      5|      2|
|   C|  0|2019|      6|      0|
+----+---+----+-------+-------+
```

**Where:**

1. set up WindSpec `w1` to sort rows by `case`, `year` and then use [lag](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) function to find the previous value (similar to *shift* in pandas).

   ```
   pandas: (~(df.case == df.case.shift())) | (df.y.shift()==1) 
   pyspark: ~(F.col("case") == F.lag("case").over(w1)) | (F.lag("y",1,0).over(w1) == 1)
   ```

   **Note:**
   (1) *orderBy* in `w1` is important since *partitionBy* triggers data shuffling and the order of the resulting rows is not guaranteed otherwise. (2) be caution about the **null** values using lag function, use the 3rd argument of lag function or [coalesce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) function to set up default if needed.
2. use `F.when(..,1).otherwise(0)` to convert the result of (1) from *boolean* into *int* and then do `cumsum`:

   ```
   pandas: df.c.cumsum()
   pyspark: F.sum(c).over(w1)+1
   ```
3. add *case_id* into partitionBy to set up `w2` and then do `cumcount` (no need to do another `cumsum` and then `groupby`):

   ```
   pandas: df.groupby(..).cumcount()
   pyspark: F.count('*').over(w2)-1
   ```

For a large dataframe, setting a WinSpec without `partitionBy` will move all data into a single partition which could yield **OOM** error. In fact, if you are just looking for `cumcount` inside each combination of *case* + *case_id*, you are more likely do the following:

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy('case').orderBy('year')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('case', 'case_id').orderBy('year')

df_new = pdf.withColumn("case_id", F.sum(F.when(F.lag("y",1,0).over(w1) == 1,1).otherwise(0)).over(w1)) \
    .withColumn('counter', F.count('*').over(w2)-1)

df_new.show()
+----+---+----+-------+-------+
|case|  y|year|case_id|counter|
+----+---+----+-------+-------+
|   B|  0|2016|      0|      0|
|   B|  1|2017|      0|      1|
|   B|  0|2018|      1|      0|
|   B|  0|2019|      1|      1|
|   C|  0|2016|      0|      0|
|   C|  0|2017|      0|      1|
|   C|  1|2018|      0|      2|
|   C|  0|2019|      1|      0|
|   A|  0|2016|      0|      0|
|   A|  1|2017|      0|      1|
|   A|  0|2018|      1|      0|
|   A|  0|2019|      1|      1|
+----+---+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: I am excited to try this out -- thank you for the detailed answer!